# Cocoon getting epoch time id from new nested item

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I'm using cocoon in an app to manage my nested fields.  As you may know, when a new cocoon item is added, its fields are given an id according to the epoch time in milliseconds, meaning that a new field would receive an id like `parent_model_children_attributes_1460543988970_field`.

I am using the `.on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, insertedItem){` callback to add some additional functionality that requires that exact epoch timestamp.  I've tried looking at `e.timeStamp` but that gives the time of the event which is usually a bit off from the id number itself.

Is there an elegant way to get that EXACT number?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you are trying to do? You get the `inserted_item` so you can use jquery to get any id or class you want, but in most cases it is not even needed, because you can manipulate the `inserted_item` to set/add/change stuff at will anway/directly.

Comment: @nathanvda Thanks for the response; sorry to leave you hanging, I must have missed the notification.  I actually ended up writing a plugin to strip away the stuff surrounding the timestamp.  Sort of a hack but worked well enough.